# Check type of JSON input while deserializing

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have 2 different types of JSON that I may receive from the server.

For example I may get:

```
{
 id:value,
 name:value,
 time:value
}
```

or

```
{
 id:value,
 name:value,
 image:value
}
```

Is there a way I can test to check which JSON it is and then perform further operations?

Current I am using [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to create an object based on the JSON input. Is there a way I can use GSON itself to get this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSON is in a JsonObject, you can do something like this:

```
if (object.has("time")) {
  Time time = gson.fromJson(object, Time.class);
} else {
  Image image = gson.fromJson(object, Image.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're out of the deserialization context (in sense of more operations, not just `gson.fromJson(...)`, at a call site), you can use [jdebon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4345848/jdebon)'s answer. If you're going to detect it within deserialization process, you can create a custom type adapter (only if you have a common base class though due to fundamental Gson restrictions that prohibit to bind `java.lang.Object`). For example:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Base.class, (JsonDeserializer<Base>) (jsonElement, type, context) -> {
            final JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
            final boolean hasImage = jsonObject.has("image");
            final boolean hasTime = jsonObject.has("time");
            if ( hasImage && hasTime ) {
                throw new JsonParseException("Cannot handle both image and time");
            }
            if ( hasImage ) {
                return context.deserialize(jsonElement, Image.class);
            }
            if ( hasTime ) {
                return context.deserialize(jsonElement, Time.class);
            }
            throw new JsonParseException("Cannot parse " + jsonElement);
        })
        .create();
```

```java
abstract class Base {

    final int id = Integer.valueOf(0);
    final String name = null;

}
```

```java
final class Image
        extends Base {

    final String image = null;

}
```

```java
final class Time
        extends Base {

    final String time = null;

}
```

Example:

```java
for ( final String resource : ImmutableList.of("image.json", "time.json") ) {
    try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = getPackageResourceJsonReader(Q44227327.class, resource) ) {
        final Base base = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Base.class);
        System.out.println(base.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

Output:

> Image
>   Time